Python-Polars. Method.find() returns an incorrect value for strings when using utf-8 characters
The behavior of the str.find() method in polars differs from str.find() in pandas in Python. Is there a parameter for processing utf-8 characters? Or is it a bug?
Example code in python:
import polars as pl

# Define a custom function that wraps the str.find() method
def find_substring(s, substring):
    return int(s.find(substring))

# Test df
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "text": ["testтестword",None,'']
})

# Apply the custom function to the "text" column using map_elements()
substr = 'word'
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.col('text').str.find(substr,literal=True,strict=True).alias('in_polars'),   
    pl.col("text").map_elements(lambda s: find_substring(s, substr), return_dtype=pl.Int64).alias('find_check')
)

print(df)


Results:

There is no parameter in the documentation for setting the character encoding.
Using my function is a solution, but it's very slow.
Can you suggest something faster and without map_elements? Thanks.
pl.col("text").map_elements(lambda s: find_substring(s, substr), return_dtype=pl.Int64).alias('find_check')


https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/14190 - As for a faster alternative, it probably depends on what the overall goal is. Will you be using the index for a specific task?

Python doesn't work with UTF-8 strings, it works with Unicode strings.  s.find() is returning the correct value.  It appears polars may be converting to UTF-8 byte-strings based on the returned values, not sure what you can do about that.

For the record, the distinction here is that python counts characters (code points, I'd guess) and rust counts utf-8 bytes. Python is not actually counting what you'd consider “characters”, as normalization affects the result of find. What do you wish to do with the result of find?

The result of .find() is then used to slice the string after the found substring. Example: url.str.slice(url.str.find('?')). I'll take a look .extract() https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/14190

There is an open issue on the Github tracker.

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/14190


I think we should update the docs to make clear that we return byte offsets.


As for the actual goal - it seems you want split a string into 2 parts and take the right hand side.
You could use regex e.g. with .str.extract()
df.with_columns(after = pl.col("url").str.extract(r"\?(.*)"))

shape: (1, 2)
┌────────────────────────────────────┬──────────────┐
│ url                                ┆ after        │
│ ---                                ┆ ---          │
│ str                                ┆ str          │
╞════════════════════════════════════╪══════════════╡
│ https://тестword.com/?foo=bar&id=1 ┆ foo=bar&id=1 │
└────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────┘

.str.splitn() could be another option.
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "url": ["https://тестword.com/?foo=bar&id=1"]
})

df.with_columns(
    pl.col("url").str.splitn("?", 2)
      .struct.rename_fields(["before", "after"])
      .struct.unnest()
)

shape: (1, 3)
┌────────────────────────────────────┬───────────────────────┬──────────────┐
│ url                                ┆ before                ┆ after        │
│ ---                                ┆ ---                   ┆ ---          │
│ str                                ┆ str                   ┆ str          │
╞════════════════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════╪══════════════╡
│ https://тестword.com/?foo=bar&id=1 ┆ https://тестword.com/ ┆ foo=bar&id=1 │
└────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────┴──────────────┘

It returns a Struct which we rename/unnest into columns.

.struct.rename_fields()
.struct.unnest()

